# Adjust a JS Expand/Collapse function that has a bit of a bump in its fluidity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been implementing this awesome JS/Jquery expand/collapse function into a page, but it's got a little kink to it that I'd like to fix.

Specifically, the problem is that when you first click on the link **Websites ▾**, the menu expands nicely, but just before it's done it has a little jump to it, which I'd like to remove. The jump doesn't occur in the JS Fiddle, nor does it occurr when clicking to expand/collapse after the intial click, so I suspect my CSS might be the issue, but I'm just not sure.

***Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time.***

The JS was borrowed from this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/eK8X5/7/)

And here's [a test page](http://jamiekayam.com/JSTest.html) I've published

Additionaly, here's all the code (stripped of some excess content to simplify)

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/webfonts.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/expandcollapse.js"></script>
    </head>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <span>
                <p>&nbsp; Websites &#9662;</p>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Human Rights Symbols</p>
            <p>
                Cornerstone Parks
            </p>
            <p>
                Eileen Fisher (Video Page)
            </p>
            <p>
                Suzy B Fine Jewelry*
            </p>
            <p class="para2">Niki International</p>
            <p class="para2">Eliza's Eyes</p>
            <p class="para2">Fabrikant-Tara</p>
            <p class="para2">Branded Jewelry</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h2>*To view password-protected links, 
        please request access by phone or email.
    </h2>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


.container {
    /* Expand Collapse Styling */
    width:100%;

}
.container div {
    width:100%;
}
.container .header {

    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'oxygenregular', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
    color: gray;
}
.container .content {

    display: none;

}




#LightSlateGrayBar {
    /* Color: LightSlateGray, #778899, hsl(210, 22%, 60%) */
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: rgba(119, 136, 153, 0.95);

}

.TopBar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}

.BottomBar {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: -3px -3px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}


#box {
    min-width: 600px;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    text-align: center; 
}

p {
    font-family: 'oxygenregular', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
    color: gray;
}

.para2 {
    color: LightGray;
}

.paraBlue {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #25438d;
    margin-top: 26px;
}


h1 {
    font-family: 'rokkittregular', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 42px;
    color: #25438d;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
}

.hyphen {
    font-size: 34px;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
}


h2 {
    font-family: 'oxygenregular', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    line-height: 12px;
    color: gray;    
}


a:link {
transition: all 1s linear 0;
transition-timing-function: ease-in;
text-decoration:none;
color: gray;
}

a:visited { 
text-decoration:none;
color: #8F8F8F;
}

a:hover {
text-decoration:underline;
color: black;
}

a:active { 
text-decoration:none;
color: lightGray;
}


.heading {
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
}
```

**JS**

```
// JavaScript Document

$(function() {
  $(".header").click(function () {

    $header = $(this);
    //getting the next element
    $content = $header.next();
    //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
    $content.slideToggle(500, function () {
        //execute this after slideToggle is done
        //change text of header based on visibility of content div
        $header.html(function () {
            //change text based on condition
            return $content.is(":visible") ? "Websites &#9652;" : "Websites &#9662;";
        });
    });

  });
});
```

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle for your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially the content inside your `div#header` is

```
<div class="header">
 <span>
 <p>&nbsp; Websites &#9662;</p>
 </span>
</div>
```

From the first toggle onwards it'll change to

```
Websites &#9662; // only the arrows character codes changes on further clicks, structure is same
```

without `<span>` and `<p>` elements, causing a difference in size, which in turn causes the jump. Returning the proper html content as the initial state like

```
return $content.is(":visible") ? "<span><p>&nbsp; Websites &#9652;</p></span>" : "<span><p>&nbsp; Websites &#9662; </p></span>";
```

or changing the content initially to

```
<div class="header">
 Websites &#9662;
</div>
```

Should fix the problem..

Comment: now I have a follow up question. When the expand function opens the div, there's another small kink at the bottom that effects the last div of smaller-styled text. Any suggestion on how to fix that too?

Comment: @user3495670 i didn't get it, are you talking about the movement cased by scrollbar appearing?

Comment: No, not from the scroll bar. When you expand the menu it drops down smoothly, but then the div below it pops upward by about 5px at the end of the movement. When you collapse the menu, that same bottom div moves at the beginning of the function. It's minimal in comparison to the original issue, but it's noticable. Wonder what it could be.